# Call a static function into the class React ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following ReactJS class:

```
import React from 'react'

export class Content extends React.Component {

  static getValue(key) {
    return key
  }

  render() {
    let value = this.getValue(this.props.valueKey);
    return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}} />
  }
}
```

But I have the following error:

```
TypeError: this.getValue is not a function
```

I don't understand.  Is this the good way to call a static function? I think react is doing something with statics, but I don't know what.

Comment: *"is it the good way to call a static function ?"* Since it doesn't work, probably not :P

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A static method needs to be accessed on the class not an instance. So in your case, use:

`Content.getValue()`

However, a static method won't be able to access `this` -- I don't think you want the method to be static based on your code sample above.

More: [Static Members in ES6](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx)

Comment: The 'getValue' function itself is static - so it can be called with this.constructor.getValue(params)... I use this method often in my code. I don't see a reason for this function not to be static, unless 'this' needs to be called inside the function.

Answer (score 19):

You can access from within the class as `this.constructor.getValue`.

Edit: I've added a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/92099/). The only change I made was adding the function call from the constructor and removing the dangerously set innerHTML - As shown, you can access the getValue static from this.constructor, and works just fine.

Comment: Not with `React.Component`

Comment: Incorrect - you can. Trust me on this one. I'll add a JSBin

Comment: @GeoffreyAbdallah this is very interesting. So you can also pass instance object as parameter to static class and can still access it is props like it is not not static. very cool

Comment: Interesting that we need to go though the constructor. Hm. Why is this?

Comment: @OliverDixon because "this.contrstructor" points on constructor function itself. so it's equal to `Content.getValue` but without need to hard code class name