# Reactjs → static methods without access to "this", what's the alternative?

Tags: reactjs, this, static-methods, setstate

EDITED: Static methods don't have access to "this". The underlying question is then, how in reactjs should you organize the code, if you'd like to separate functionalities in different classes? the only way to call the methods of these classes is then by making them "static". Is it really the only way? What are you supposed to do? Create one big class so that all methods will have access to "this"?

EDITED2: What I have done is then to avoid writing a static method that needs to have access to the state. In particular, I've used a promise to return the value to the class that does have access to the state.

```
 static Parse(cvs_string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Papa.parse(cvs_string, {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: (results) => resolve(results)
        });
    });
 }
```

EDITED3: But, as said in the comments, it's nonesense to build a class that also extends from Component if the main reason is to provide helper functions, so at the end:

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';

export const ParseCsv = (csv_string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Papa.parse(csv_string, {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: (results) => resolve(results)
        });
    });
}
```

---- [previous]

Why is this not working? Shouldn't I have access to setstate here?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse';

class PapaParse extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Parse = this.Parse.bind(this);
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }

  static Parse(cvs_string) {
    Papa.parse(cvs_string, {
      header: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
//    complete: (results) => { // this gives the same error
      complete: function(results) {
        PapaParse.updateData(results);
      }
    });
  }

  static updateData(results) {
    console.log(results); // results are the expected ones
    PapaParse.setState({data: results.data}); // here the error, or
    this.setState({data: results.data}); // here the same error
  }

}

export default PapaParse;
```

I can solve this by sending "this" as a variable, in

```
PapaParse.Parse(response, this);
```

and then in the PapaParse component

```
static Parse(cvs_string, that) {
...
PapaParse.updateData(results, that);
...
static updateData(results, that) {
...
that.setState({data: results.data});
```

So I understand that the "this" is lost when I'm calling a method of a componenet without invoking it with the "tag", and merely calling it as a static method.

Then, what I'm doing here is what I'm supposed to do? Or what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a static function into the class React ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672135/call-a-static-function-into-the-class-react-es6)

Comment: But then, how can I call a method from an "object" if I don't "invoke" the object by using the tag? do I have any alternative to using static methods?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what you're asking. Don't use static methods, make everything an arrow function, and call `this.updateData(results)`.

Comment: You are trying to update instance object (state) from static method. You cant do that. Not really sure why you are using static methods here anyway. Make them instance methods.

Comment: I'm now searching for use cases for static methods. I'm using them because in order to keep code organized, I have a (static) component for parsing text. How can I access to the methods of this class without using them as static methods?

Comment: You should think of static methods as something completely separate from class instances. Static methods can't interact with class instances (which React components necessarily are.) If you need to update state or internal data or instance variable or just about anything else, you can't use static methods. They're mainly used for helper functions like transforming one object to another.

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure what the actual problem here is. The `Papa.parse()` method can just as well be static in the other class, but this React component that uses it shouldn't have static methods (because React creates instances of the component.) And I don't really see why just removing the `static` keywords from this class makes it less organized.

Comment: but if I remove the static keyword, then I cannot access to the method by using Classname.method(), can I?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to?

Comment: and then how can I call the method? I mean, I have a class that has a method that will use papaparse to parse a string. How can I access to this method from another component? AFAIK, since I have not called the class in ReactDOM.render then I can only declare the methods as static and call them with the class name. If it's not the case, how can I call that method?

Comment: If you're not using the class as a React component, then why are you making it a React component? That seems to be the core issue here. There's no reason whatsoever to extend `React.Component` if the component doesn't have a `render()` method and is never used in the DOM. If you want to make a helper class then just make it a normal class that doesn't extend anything.

Comment: Exactly! that's the core issue here, I've added your help in the question, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods are intended for code that doesn't depend on class instance, because there's none. There are not so many good use cases for static methods, because if a function isn't directly linked to a class as an entity, it possibly doesn't need to be a part of it. One of use cases is React component [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) hook which is pure function that needs to defined as a method (because it's a hook that should be accessed as class property by the framework), it forces a developer to not use class instance and focus on function input and output.

Since the method needs class instance and `setState` instance method in particular, static methods are not applicable here. None of these methods should be static:

```
class PapaParse extends Component {
  Parse(cvs_string) {
    Papa.parse(cvs_string, {
      header: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: (results) => {
        this.updateData(results);
      }
    });
  }

  updateData(results) {
    console.log(results);
    this.setState({data: results.data});
  }

}
```

This is same problem as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276483/react-anti-pattern/52276827#52276827):

```
this.Parse = this.Parse.bind(this);
```

It's a mistake to bind static method to class instance, especially in a class that isn't a singleton by design and is expected to be instantiated multiple times (React component class is). There can be multiple class instances, this may result in bugs and memory leaks.

If `Parse` method is supposed to be triggered outside this class, this should be done in a way that is idiomatic to React, e.g. get `PapaParse` component ref in parent component and access instance method on it:

```
// in constructor
this.papaParseRef = React.createRef();
...
// in render
<PapaParse ref={this.papaParseRef}/>
```

The method will be available as `this.papaParseRef.current.Parse()` after render.

Comment: I am starting to know how react thinks, thanks a lot for the info. How would I get a ref of the class in parent component?

Comment: With `this.papaParseRef = React.createRef()` in constructor and `<PapaParse ref={papaParseRef}`/> in render, the method will be available as `this.papaParseRef.current.Parse()` after render. The code is for React 16.3. See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: cool, didn't heard of it (but only few days of experience with react so far). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`PapaParse.setState({data: results.data}); // here the error`

Should be `this.setState` so you reference the instance, not the class.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I already tested both, both give the same error (updated)

Answer (score -1):

Declare `updatedata()` as an arrow function.

```
updatedata=(results) => {
   //this.setState will work here
}
```

Comment: I've also tested updatedata = (results) => {...}, the same error