# How to call a static method from another static method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, jsx

I am trying to call a static method from within another static method in a React component:

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

  static add(a, b){
    return a + b;
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    const sum = this.add(2, 2);    
    return {
      sum
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello World</div>
  }
}
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rmxy909ovo

But I get the error that `this` is undefined, even though [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#From_another_static_method):

> In order to call a static method within another static method of the
>   same class, you can use the this keyword.

Why is `this` in a static method undefined and how to call the method `add` within `getDerivedStateFromProps` in this example?

Comment: Use `HelloWorld.add()` (it does work in the browser, apparently not for transpiled ES6 though)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a static function into the class React ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672135/call-a-static-function-into-the-class-react-es6)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate because I want to call a static method *from another static* method, not an instance method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If static method is called with respective context as `HelloWorld.getDerivedStateFromProps()`, `this` will refer to class constructor inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`, `this === HelloWorld`.

This is not the case for `getDerivedStateFromProps`. It is a hook, its purpose as class static method is to associate provided function with specific component. It's called as a callback by the render without `this` context provided. It was designed like that specifically to isolate it from class instance and prevent possible misuses that are common in legacy lifecycle hooks (`componentWillReceiveProps`, etc).

The real problem here is that `add` shouldn't be `HelloWorld` method because it doesn't belong to the class. Since it cannot access component instance, it's only a function that uses the class as a namespace. Using classes as namespaces is antipattern in modern JS. Instead, it could be:

```
function add(a, b){
  return a + b;
}

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    const sum = add(2, 2);    
    return {
      sum
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Yola It does, in a sane way, because the thing that the OP contains shouldn't be done. Component class shouldn't be used as a namespace for generic functions, it isn't a proper class that is instantiated as is, but a blueprint for a component. OP tried to use static methods as such, while getDerivedStateFromProps is a hook.

Comment: I came here searching how to call static from static. And I don't see this part in your answer. You likely helped the guy in this specific situation but for people coming from a search engine, this is a no-answer. I'm ready to change -1 to +1 if you either explain this in your post or edit the question to make it appear in proper search queries.

Answer (score 5):

A static method needs to be accessed on the class not an instance. So try this:

```
HelloWorld.add(2,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** This answer is incorrect, sorry. I should have double-checked that @ChrisG's comment was correct before posting it. @estus's answer is the correct answer.

If you paste your code into the Babel playground you can see that calling `HelloWorld.getDerivedStateFromProps()` directly indeed works as you intended, even compiling to ES5.

---

Original (**incorrect**) answer:

(Note that this answer is only partially incorrect; using `this` to call one static method from another is indeed valid syntax in normal circumstances.)

While I personally don't find it as readable as using the class name (`HelloWorld`) explicitly, the code you originally posted is valid, and MDN is correct. As @ChrisG pointed out in his comment, the problem is that it doesn't work in code transpiled by Babel to ES5. If you change the target so it transpiles to ES6, it should work, although of course it won't work in browsers that don't support ES6.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can't find this object in static method. But you can achive this in other hand. You can declare a global variable and assign "this object" reference to that in constructor.
You can check below code:-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
var _this;
class Toastr extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      visible: 'hide'
    }
    _this = this
  } 

  static handleShow = (isSuccess, message, code) => {
    _this.setState({visible: 'show', message: message})
    setTimeout( function(){
      _this.setState({visible: 'hide'})
    }, 3000)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" className="toast-conatiner">
        <div className="toast-position">
           <div className={`toast ${this.state.visible}`} role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
             <div class="toast-body">
                <span className={this.state.isSuccess ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}>{this.state.message}</span>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }

 export default Toastr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You call static method from another see below code.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps() {
   HelloWorld.add()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But why does `this` not work? Is MDN wrong?

Comment: `this` not work because the method was static so `this` can not referred in static method.

Comment: @DhavadGohel that is not correct. Using `this` to call one static method from another is valid, standards-compliant code in JS.