# this.state inside static function in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      percentage: 60,
    };
```

And also have a static function where I want to use this percentage by **this.state.percentage** ->

```
static get progressBar(){
   <div>
     <ProgressBar percentage={this.State.percentage} />
   </div>
}
```

But it shows error which is

> Unexpected 'this'(mysticatea/no-this-in-static)

Also below this code, it shows error which is

> 'percentage is missing in props validation'

```
const ProgressBar = props => (
  <div className="progress-bar">
    <Filler percentage={props.percentage} />
  </div>
);

const Filler = props => (
  <div className="filler" style={{ width: `${props.percentage}%` }} />
);
```

I do not understand why it's showing these errors. And As I am new to react so I could not get the problem.

Comment: `this` refers to the current instance while executing the function. `static` method isn't bound to any concrete instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static context is before creating instance where this is available so this is not available in static method like any other language such as Java etc...

check this out [Call static from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672135/call-a-static-function-into-the-class-react-es6)